# How to create extension for a generic structure that will be available only for Optional generic parameters in Swift 4.1?

Tags: swift, generics, swift4, extension-methods, swift4.1

I have the following structure in my iOS application:

```
struct MyStruct<T> {

    var property1: T
    var property2: T

    init(property1: T, property2: T) {
        self.property1 = property1
        self.property2 = property2
    }

    init(allPropertiesWith value: T) {
        self.property1 = value
        self.property2 = value
    }
}
```

I also have 2 classes that don't have a common ancestor:

```
class A { }
class B { }
```

In my application I have instances of `MyStruct<A>`, `MyStruct<B>`, `MyStruct<A?>`, `MyStruct<B?>` and I use them in these functions:

```
func f1(myStrurct: MyStruct<A?>) { }

func f2(myStrurct: MyStruct<A>) { }

func g2() {
    f1(myStrurct: MyStruct<A?>(property2: A()))
} 
/* I also have the same functions for MyStruct<B> and MyStruct<B?> */
```

I cannot modify `f1`, `f2` and `g2`. That's why I created 2 extensions to make initialisation of `MyStruct<T>` easier:

```
extension MyStruct where T == A? {

    init(property1: T) {
        self.property1 = property1
        self.property2 = nil
    }

    init(property2: T) {
        self.property1 = nil
        self.property2 = property2
    }
}

extension MyStruct where T == B? {

    init(property1: T) {
        self.property1 = property1
        self.property2 = nil
    }

    init(property2: T) {
        self.property1 = nil
        self.property2 = property2
    }
}
```

As you can see these extensions are almost the same. Is it possible to refactor it with only 1 extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52274083/2229783) provided by [Rakesha Shastri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7734643/rakesha-shastri) I found out that I can use `protocol` to refactor my code. However to be able to use this solution I need to rewrite other parts of my application. I tried to add the solution by Rakesha Shastri to my application and compile it with Swift 3, Swift 4 or Swift 4.2 (all Swift versions available in Xcode 10.0), but every time I received a compiler error. It means that currently there are no ways how to solve the problem that I described in this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can make both `A` and `B` (or whichever class needs it) conform to a **dummy protocol** and check that for `T`.

```
protocol MyStructProtocol {

}

class A: MyStructProtocol { }
class B: MyStructProtocol { }

extension MyStruct where T == MyStructProtocol? {
    init(property1: T) {
        self.property1 = property1
        self.property2 = nil
    }

    init(property2: T) {
        self.property1 = nil
        self.property2 = property2
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer! However now I am not able to build my application, because I have this line of code: `var myStrurct: MyStruct<A?> = MyStruct(property2: A())`. Error is `Cannot convert value of type 'MyStruct<MyStructProtocol?>' to specified type 'MyStruct<A?>'`.

Comment: @RomanPodymov weird, it compiles fine for me on the playground.

Comment: What version of Swift are you using?

Comment: @RomanPodymov Check if you running the same line `var myStrurct: MyStruct<A?> = MyStruct(property2: A())` as you posted in the comment.

Comment: I have Swift 4.1 and the build fails on the line that I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179810/discussion-between-roman-podymov-and-rakesha-shastri).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to extend anything to create such an easier constructor. Check out the modified version of your struct definition below:

```
struct MyStruct<T> {

    var property1: T?
    var property2: T?

    init(property1: T? = nil, property2: T? = nil) {
        if T.self == String.self {
            self.property1 = property1
            self.property2 = nil
        }
        else if T.self == Int.self {
            self.property1 = nil
            self.property2 = property2
        }
    }

    init(allPropertiesWith value: T) {
        self.property1 = value
        self.property2 = value
    }
}
```

Then you can use initialize them as you wish with following lines.

```
MyStruct<String>(property2: "sadsad")
MyStruct<Int>(property1: 23)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However sometimes `property1` and `property2` should be non-optional, so I expect to call `MyStruct<A>(allPropertiesWith: A()).property1.method`, not `MyStruct<A>(allPropertiesWith: A()).property1?.method`.